# Mongoose populate not populating

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, mongoose-populate

I am trying to populate my users car inventory. All the cars have a userId attached to them when they are created but when I go to populate the inventory it doesn't work and I get no errors.

Here are my models:

**User.js**

```
let UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  inventory: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Car' }]
});

let User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
models.User = User;
```

**Cars.js**

```
let CarSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  make: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  model: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  year: {
    type: String
  }
});

let Car = mongoose.model('Car', CarSchema);
models.Car = Car;
```

Here is the populate code:

```
router.route('/users/:user/inventory').get((req, res) => {
    User.findById(userId)
      .populate('inventory') 
      .exec((err, user) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("ERRROORRR " + err)
          return res.send(err);
        }

        console.log('Populate ' + user)
        res.status(200).json({message: 'Returned User', data: user});
      });
    });
  };
```

This is what a car object looks like in the database:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5759c00d9928cb581b5424d0"),
  "make": "dasda",
  "model": "dafsd",
  "year": "asdfa",
  "userId": ObjectId("575848d8d11e03f611b812cf"),
  "__v": 0
}
```

Any advice would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Populate in Mongoose currently only works with `_id`'s, though there's a [long-standing issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2562) to change this.  You'll need to make sure your Car model has an `_id` field and that the `inventory` field in User is an array of these `_id`'s.

```
let CarSchema = new mongoose.Schema(); //implicit _id field - created by mongo
// Car { _id: 'somerandomstring' }

let UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  inventory: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Car'
  }]
});
// User { inventory: ['somerandomstring'] }

User.populate('inventory')
```

Comment: So I need to add a _id field to my car model? Mongo automatically creates that for you when you save to the db. Are they not linked up the way that I currently have them? I thought the

userId: {
 type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
 ref: 'User'
},

and

inventory: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Car' }]

was doing that.

Comment: JuniorSauce which field from "Car" are you storing in that array? It should be `_id`.

Comment: The inventory field in the User model should be doing that.

Comment: JuniorSauce, not if you aren't saving the cars in the inventory correctly. Which is what I'd guess the problem is.

Comment: Oh I thought the populate would do that by picking up the userId. So I need to save the cars to the inventory some how. This is confusing haha. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yeah JuniorSauce just make sure when you look at your User data in Mongo that the "inventories" is a list of `_id`s that correspond to `_id`s of Cars

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114287/discussion-between-juniorsauce-and-harangue).